# Trying to create multiple events for multiple dynamically generated List<T> items in Windows 8 API

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I'm creating a Windows 8 app and I have the need for events to be raised during a GotFocus event for a TextBox element. I'm not sure what's wrong or which direction to go in exactly as 1. I'm not that good with events in C# to begin with, and 2. I reckon it's a bit different in WindowsRT. The TextBoxListArray() method is started through another event.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    List<TextBox> textBox = new List<TextBox>();
    List<RichEditBox> editBox = new List<RichEditBox>();
    static int tally;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TextBoxListArray()
    {
        textBox.Add(new TextBox());
        int i = textBox.Count();
        i = i - 1;
        tally = i - 1;
        textBox[i].HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        textBox[i].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        textBox[i].TextWrapping = TextWrapping.NoWrap;
        textBox[i].Margin = new Thickness(10);
        textBox[i].Text = i.ToString();
        textBox[i].IsReadOnly = true;
        textBox[i].Height = 40;
        stackNotes.Children.Add(textBox[i]);
        textBox[i].GotFocus += new EventHandler(TextBoxList_GotFocus);
    }

    private void TextBoxList_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox[tally] = sender as TextBox;
        textBox[tally].Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `I'm not sure what's wrong` - Please learn MVVM before you ever write a single line of code in any of the XAML-based technologies. Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code. That's what XAML is for.

Comment: These are not static elements and they need to be dynamically generated on a raised event. Is MVVM helpful for this? If so do you have any recommended readings?

Comment: XAML's concept of "dynamic" is really different from other UI frameworks. My point still stands. Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code. I don't have Windows 8 right now so I could not test, but I could give you a WPF-based example if you wish.

Comment: Yes, that would be helpful. I think they're close enough to get me going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem with your code is using `tally` for get the focused item from the list. since you have `sender` parameter you can cast it to a TextBox and then set the background.

there may be better approach specially for WPF as other answers.

```
private void TextBoxListArray()
{
    var tb =  new TextBox() { Text = textBox.Count(), ....... };
    tb.GotFocus += new EventHandler(TextBoxList_GotFocus);
    textBox.Add(tb);
    stackNotes.Children.Add(tb);
}

private void TextBoxList_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var txtBox = sender as TextBox;
     txtBox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow); 
}
```

Comment: I noticed the explanation now which is why I voted for your answer over mine.

Answer (score 3):

This is the `right way` to do what you're looking for in WPF (or any of the XAML-based UI frameworks)

```
<Window x:Class="MiscSamples.TextBoxItemsControlSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="TextBoxItemsControlSample" Height="300" Width="300">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=.}" x:Name="TextBox"/>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger SourceName="TextBox" Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="TextBox" Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class TextBoxItemsControlSample : Window
{
    public TextBoxItemsControlSample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(x => "Text" + x.ToString());

    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

- There is not a `single` line of code that manipulates ANY UI element. You don't need that. [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) is powerful enough to remove the need for all the horrendous hacks that were abundant in dinosaur UI frameworks.
- The [`Trigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger.aspx) makes the TextBox's Background yellow whenever `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` is true for any given TextBox. That removes the need for procedural approaches.
- I did not test this in WinRT XAML. There might be differences (such as different property names, etc).
- You can further customize the UI by defining properties of the `ItemsControl` (such as `ItemsPanel`).
- WPF / XAML rocks. Just copy and paste my code in a `File -> New Project -> WPF Application` and see the results by yourself.

Comment: 1+ @HighCore for Good answer with the explanation how to do it on WPF.

Comment: I'm not expert on WPF. Just wanted to show where was the issue in the given code

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to make it work. It's definitely a hack but it got the result I needed. I will also try it the "proper" way through XAML.

```
private void TextBoxListArray()
    {
        textBox.Add(new TextBox());
        int i = textBox.Count();
        i = i - 1;
        tally = i - 1;
        textBox[i].HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        textBox[i].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        textBox[i].TextWrapping = TextWrapping.NoWrap;
        textBox[i].Margin = new Thickness(10);
        textBox[i].Text = i.ToString();
        textBox[i].IsReadOnly = true;
        textBox[i].Height = 40;
        stackNotes.Children.Add(textBox[i]);
        textBox[i].GotFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(TextBoxList_GotFocus);
        textBox[i].LostFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(TextBoxList_LostFocus);
    }

    private void TextBoxList_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBoxSender = sender as TextBox;
        textBoxSender.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Beige);
    }

    private void TextBoxList_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBoxSender = sender as TextBox;
        textBoxSender.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    }
```

Comment: Why you assign `sender ` to `textBox[0]`? have you check my answer?

Comment: I didn't notice you actually had the same answer. The difference between the naming was subtle so it didn't catch my eye.