# Ways to generate .resx for UI string in WPF like in WinForm?

Tags: wpf, winforms, localization, resx

Coming from WinForm, I am used to the convenience that, when you change the language of a WinForm control in design mode, it automatically put all string properties with [Localizable(true)] to the resx.

Now in WPF, although I found out you can still use resx instead of locbaml with markups like Content="{x:Static resx:Resource1.Str1}", it has the drawback of having to type it in myself. Really? Am I missing some shortcut key or menu buttons that can do that me?

Please help, thanks.

(Actually, seems like everything in WPF are oriented to typing instead of design mode. I am still in a shock for having to get my spoiled sense out from the comfort zone of design mode)

Comment: Please see the [WPF Globalization and Localization Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for full details about localization. In WPF, you'll additionally need to set special `Uid` properties on *every UI control*, so no... there is no shortcut.

Comment: @Sheridan I think there's a tool that does that automatically, though

Comment: @user1249190 BTW, `seems like everything in WPF are oriented to typing instead of design mode` - Yes. The difference is that WPF actually allows you do *DO* stuff rather than having to resort to a bunch of horrible hacks for almost anything as you might have done in archaic technologies in the past. See [My Explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18927377/643085) about *why* the use of the Visual Studio designer is generally discouraged in WPF.

Comment: @HighCore, it's good to see you again... I thought you had disappeared. And yes, we can use the `msbuild /t:updateuid` function, but it won't provide useful (to the business) ID values... just unique ones. Also, the whole localization process in WPF will still take a long time to implement, so I didn't want to give the user false hope.