# How to Use WPF Controls Inside an Excel Actions Pane?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, excel, vsto

There are several resources out there that explain how to add **WinForms** controls to Excel. See these two:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e3zbk0hz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/create-excel-2007-vsto-add-in-wpf-control.aspx

Both of them mention the more up-to-date option of using **WPF controls** (the one I need). Unfortunately, both resources are lacking the fundamental part. There is a missing link:

(1) The Microsoft site mentions some video -with the exact title that matches my requirement- but all videos in that web site have been removed, it seems.

[image]

(2) The Clear-Lines site contains an outstanding, step-by-step project but alas, when the critical part is mentioned, the author uses some facility (the "WPF Interoperability section of the Toolbox") that does not exist in VS-2010+

[image]

Based on the above screenshots, and other sites, I have come to the conclusion that the missing link, the connection between my WPF UserControl and its appearance in Excel is some `ElementHost`.

Addendum for @HighCore. See Toolbox below:

[image]

Comment: Being a WPF coder, I also tried to use WPF Controls in VSTO applications, but so far I have had to use the inferior WinForms approach because it is documented.

Comment: VSTO applications work great with WPF. I am currently refactoring a Win Form app for Excel that used a browser to get custom HTML from a web service into a WPF application. The most important thing for me was learning how to manipulate the WPF to appear on the screen while NOT using a WPF application. To overcome this I started here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/yougerthen/integrate-wpf-control-in-your-excel-solutions/ which led to me the current architecture. A WPF library of Controls and Windows and a Excel plugin project. Referenced the other app and everything is good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Esteemed Self:

Your problem is that you are trying to place a **WPF Control** inside *another* **WPF Control**.

You need to create an old-fashioned **WinForm Control** and next you use the Toolbox as depicted here:

[image]

Notice that the section **ElementHost Tasks** has been renamed **WPF Interoperability** but it is otherwise very much alive.

From MSDN Magazine:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163292.aspx#S4

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you think there's a "missing link". The [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost(v=vs.110).aspx) is the standard way to host WPF content on winforms, and it's perfectly documented in the link above, and also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215(v=vs.110).aspx).

given any winforms container (such as a `Form` or `Panel`), simply do:

```
var elementHost = new ElementHost 
                  {
                      Child = new YourWPFContentHere()
                  };

this.Controls.Add(elementHost);
```

make sure you add references to these assemblies:

- PresentationCore
- PresentationFramework
- System.Xaml
- WindowsBase
- WindowsFormsIntegration

Comment: I guess I was looking for a pure WPF solution, then. BTW: Both the video and the "WPF Interoperability section of the Toolbox" are definitely missing.

Comment: @swiss_programmer I'm not familiar with the "toolbox" (whatever that is), but the above code should work.

Comment: Toolbox = Ctrl-Alt-X in Visual Studio.

Comment: HighCore: do you have experience with VSTO? Is is really hard to find good info (such as the one subject of this post) about it.

Comment: @swiss_programmer I was being sarcastic dude, you don't need any "toolbox" in WPF because there's XAML you can write. No, unfortunately I don't have any experience with VSTO, but if you can host winforms content, you surely can host WPF content via the ElementHost.

Comment: Okay - You remind me of a colleague who typed HTML the way a novelist types English, at high speed. That was before the introduction of visual HTML tools. I am slowly learning my way to XAML, after being intimidated by it. Will try your suggestion.

Comment: @swiss_programmers both HTML and XAML, being markup languages, lend themselves to use manual typing rather than visual designers. for XAML in particular, the Visual Studio designer generates a lot of unwanted, unmaintainable attributes for XAML tags. See [My explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18927377/643085) of why the use of the Visual Studio designer is discouraged in WPF, and why creating your own XAML is the preferred way.

Comment: "the Visual Studio designer generates a lot of unwanted, unmaintainable attributes for XAML tags." @HighCore: Just like computers watch over our shoulders and prevent us from making mistakes, it is our duty to reciprocate and watch over the best-effort code generated by Visual Studio. Such code is bound to become better and better (unlike human intelligence :-(