# Hosting WPF content directly in TaskPane

Tags: c#, wpf, vsto, office-interop

Is there a way to host WPF `UserControl` (or `Window`) directly in a custom task pane, either through Office Interop or some clever HWND play etc? Has anyone done it before? Note that I know about the popular `ElementHost` method and have done it countless number of times before. I'm looking for somehow eliminating the need of a WinForms component.

It would help if someone could even point to an official document which confirms that it isn't possible.

[This suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851562/how-to-use-wpf-controls-inside-an-excel-actions-pane) asks us to use `ElementHost` which is precisely what I'm looking to avoid.

Comment: You need the component to support the WPF control.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Use WPF Controls Inside an Excel Actions Pane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851562/how-to-use-wpf-controls-inside-an-excel-actions-pane)

Comment: @Chris: Thanks for the pointer, but as I said in the post, I know how to use `ElementHost`. The very purpose of this question is to find a way of getting rid of it. Please remove the duplicate flag, as the post your have linked only shows the `ElementHost` way.